# Hi I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu in php with mysql and having lots of trouble

Tags: php, html, mysql

The database name is sloganstreet and the table is slogan, and the column i'm trying to pull from is called text.  Any help would be appreciated. I have established the connection to the database but I can't seem to get the dropdown to populate with the info from mysql. thanks.

```
<label>Select a slogan:</label>
<select name="select_slogan">

    <?php
    $query = "SELECT text from slogansstreet";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    echo "<select name='Slogan'>";
    echo "<option value='0'>-Select-</option>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row['text']."'></option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Is your problem that the dropdown is empty, or that there are no elements in it at all? Because you have no text to appear in the dropdown, as there is nothing between `<option></option>`, you only assign a value (which is hidden to the user). You also likely want `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` (based on how you use the index).

Comment: the drop down is empty and it spits out a huge error on my index: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in..."

Comment: It would be usful to see the error message

Comment: I tried what you said, but when i remove label, and <select> i lose the dropdown box and get a new error :"arse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ..."

Comment: @orangutat Update your question with the code you are actually using, and which line the error is generated on.

Comment: the full error is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/ubuntu/workspace/slogansstreet/slogan/views/slogan_form.php on line 18"        

line 18 is     echo "<option value='".$row['text']."'>$row['text']</option>";

Comment: That should be `echo "<option value='".$row['text']."'>".$row['text']."</option>";` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that added the drop down back but it still doesn't populate the dropdown and is spitting out this error

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

I'm trying to fetch strings, do I need single quotes somewhere that I am missing?  Thanks.

Comment: After `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);`, can you do `var_dump($result);` and `var_dump($conn);`, and post that output?

Comment: I did and it didn't change anything? I will post the whole error code below sorry for poor formatting:


 Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sloganstreet/slogan/views/greeting_form.php on line 19
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0003 240096 {main}( ) ../index.php:0
2 0.0028 257192 render( ) ../index.php:21
3 0.0031 258168 require( '/home/ubuntu/workspace/slogansstreet/slogan/views/slogan_form.php' ) ../helpers.php:16
4 0.0036 258832 mysqli_fetch_assoc ( ) ../slogan_form.php:19

Comment: @orangutat These errors are a **completely new question** and relate to code you have not shown in this question.Please ask another question

Comment: i'm sorry. it still isn't populating the dropdown and i don't see what's wrong with the code?

Comment: @riggsfolly i'm sorry i'm confused, the code you provided below does not work and does not populate the dropdown? I just want to know what's wrong with mine, thanks for your time.

Comment: @orangutat Thats because your query is failing, does the query run when you run it from phpMyAdmin or similiar tool? Show your `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: ALSO: Your error talks about `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` which is not in the code you show. **Your error may well be somewhere else in your code that you are not showing us!!!** Thats why I suggested that you should **ask another question** as this error is not related to this question

Comment: @riggsfolly I have implemented the edited code below and i get the error:


Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/ubuntu/workspace/module7/studios/slogansstreet/slogan/views/slogan_form.php on line 30

line 30:

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))

i'm sorry i'm so dumb, i don't understand why it's not fetching and populating to the dropdown

Comment: Its not fetching data BECAUSE the QUERY `$query = "SELECT text from slogansstreet"; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);` HAS FAILED
` **Have you made a connection to your database BEFORE this code was run?**

Comment: Did you add the `IF` I added after that query code?

Comment: @riggsfolly yes, this is for a class and they set up the connection for us, i don't need to implement anything like:

<?php mysql_connect("Host Name", "User Name", "User Password") or die("Connection Failed"); mysql_select_db("DataBase Name")or die("Connection Failed"); ?>

Comment: @riggsfolly yes i did.

Comment: Sorry.... You always need to connect... somewhere in your code

Comment: ok, i'll try that and see if it works, thanks!

Comment: Please dont amend your question with anything other than _more detail_ It makes the answers look foolish and reduces there use for others to look at and solve similiar problems of their own.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have done everything twice, but missed putting something in the dropdown that the user can see.

You dont need this line, as you do this in the PHP code as well, so remove it

```
<select name="select_slogan">
```

All you need is this

I added some error processing as well, as you seem to be getting a error in that query.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $query = "SELECT text from slogansstreet";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if ( $result === FALSE ) {
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
        exit;
    }


    echo "<select name='Slogan'>";
    echo "<option value='0'>-Select-</option>";

    // add MYSQLI_ASSOC as the second param, so you dont get 
    // a numeric and an associative array returned
    // and waste memory
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<option value='{$row['text']}'>{$row['text']}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```